# Quirky Linux Permissions Errors

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, selinux

I am getting some quirky permissions errors with apache, I can access documents under by apache home directory but not under any other directory.

When I view my Apache error_log it shows

```
[error] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

I have file and folder permission set to 777 and I know my httpd.conf is setup correctly.

Here is the odd thing

when I execute this for a file in apache's directory it works fine

```
su -s /bin/bash -c "cat /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html" apache
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

When I execute this for an outside file with the same permissions I get

```
su -s /bin/bash -c "cat /var/www/html/index.html" apache
cat: /var/www/html/index.html: Permission denied
```

I thought this must be an selinux thing so I turned that off by setting SELINUX=disabled in /etc/selinux/config and restarting the server but that didn't work.

I am using a fresh install of CentOS 4.8 and my web directories are rsync'ed over from my primary web server.

**Update**

```
 ls -lZ
Sorry, this option can only be used on a SELinux kernel.

 id apache
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache)

ls -l /var /var/www /var/www/html /var/www/html/index.html

-rwxrwxrwx   1 apache apache    7 Jan 18 15:36 /var/www/html/index.html

/var:
total 192
drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root    4096 Dec 28 09:04 account
drwxr-xr-x   9 root    root    4096 Dec 28 09:04 cache
drwxr-xr-x   3 netdump netdump 4096 Dec 28 09:04 crash
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    root    4096 Dec 28 09:04 db
drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root    4096 Dec 29 13:31 doc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    root    4096 Dec 28 09:04 empty
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    root    4096 Dec 28 09:06 ftp
drwxr-xr-x   7 root    root    4096 Jan 15 10:24 httpdocs
drwxr-xr-x   7 root    root    4096 Dec 29 13:31 installed_packages
drwxr-xr-x  24 root    root    4096 Jan  4 09:54 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root    4096 Feb 21  2005 local
drwxrwxr-x   6 root    lock    4096 Jan 19 04:02 lock
drwxr-xr-x  12 root    root    4096 Jan 19 07:50 log
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root      10 Dec 28 09:03 mail -> spool/mail
drwxr-x---   5 root    named   4096 Jul 29 14:10 named
drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root    4096 Feb 21  2005 nis
drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root    4096 Feb 21  2005 opt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root    4096 Feb 21  2005 preserve
drwxr-xr-x  22 root    root    4096 Jan 19 07:44 run
drwxr-xr-x  14 root    root    4096 Dec 28 09:04 spool
drwxrwxrwt   2 root    root    4096 Jan 15 04:30 tmp
drwx------   2 root    root    4096 Feb 21  2005 tux
drwxr-xr-x   8 root    root    4096 Nov 12 05:56 www
drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root    4096 Jan 19 10:26 www2
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    root    4096 Dec 28 09:04 yp

/var/www:
total 48
drwxr-xr-x   2 root      root 4096 Nov 12 05:56 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root      root 4096 Dec 28 09:16 error
drwxr-xr-x   2 root      root 4096 Jan 18 15:36 html
drwxr-xr-x   3 root      root 4096 Dec 28 09:16 icons
drwxr-xr-x  13 root      root 4096 Dec 28 09:16 manual
drwxr-xr-x   2 webalizer root 4096 Jan 19 04:02 usage

/var/www/html:
total 8
-rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache 7 Jan 18 15:36 index.html
```

Comment: have you double checked selinux in your running system? can you show the output of `ls -lZ` from both files? what says `getenforce`?

Comment: Can you provide the output of the following two commands?
id apache
ls -l /var /var/www /var/www/html /var/www/html/index.html

Comment: updated post to include additional commands

Comment: Oops - I meant 'ls -ld /var .../index.html', but I got what I wanted.  That's strange...what happens if you actually become the user - don't just use 'su -c', try '/bin/su - apache' and then cat the file.  And if that doesn't work, as apache try to do 'ls -ld / /var /var/www ...'.  It's strange - the permissions look ok...I'm not seeing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've posted I'd say you need to give apache permissions to access /var.

Comment: wow, you are right! This was one thing I did not notice or check. Some how I got 700 on /var (I guess it must been a mistyped rsync command?), I can't believe I haven't had any other problems.

Comment: Most of the other stuff is probably running as root.  Had I asked you to run the right command the first time, we would have seen that.

Answer (score 0):

**[error] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied**

A CGI or plugin may be trying to create a file in /. See if you can track down exactly what operation is creating the error.